# Is there a way to send invoice or a link through email from which someone can pay me on stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am developing a hotel management website, I need to send my customer a link through gmail (from which they can pay me without visiting my website) but i cant find anything from stripe api doc.
and the only possible way is create a payment from using stripe.js on my website and send that link to my customer.

So I'm just curious is it possible what i'm trying to achieve ?

I have trie to create a customer but it requires card details but i dont want to get those from my website i want them to pay from stripe link

Comment: The answer is yes it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to generate a source with Stripe following their documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources

If the source type/flow is redirect, then a redirect array will be set on the source object that you receive from Stripe. This array will contain a URL that must be visited by the user paying the invoice in order to authorize the charge. Once authorized, Stripe will send a source.chargeable event via webhook. At this point you must retrieve the source and create a charge: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges